# Large Data File Output

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to output a file in java using FileWriter and PrintWriter and facing a few issues regarding the same. 
When i write the data in the file only about 85% of the data is written in the file whereas when I check using a counter and printing the data it shows 100% completion of the process. Logically all of the data should have had been written in the file but this does not happen.
I tried to search for the answer all over and what I found is that this may be due to the large data that I am writting (around 11 mb).

So is there is any efficient way in which I can complete my task?

Comment: Do you close/flush your writers?

Comment: Please show a snippet of your code in question. And as Pshemo asked, make sure you flush your writer.

Comment: Actually I do not flush my buffer. I am not sure hoe is it done. can you please explain about it a little.

Comment: Flushing is not needed, but closing the writer is.

Answer (score 1):

11 MB is pretty small so if you don't close the file correctly the end of the file could be buffered and discarded.  In Java you can write multi TB files, i.e. as large as your file system can handle. ;)

Comment: Some file systems cannot write files much bigger. e.g. ext4 is limited to 16 TB.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close FileWriter object and flush PrintWriter object.

```
objFileWriter.close();
ibjPrintWriter.flush();
```

Comment: This will throw `IOException`.

Comment: flush is a total waste unless you use BufferedXXX. And flush is a total waste before calling `close()`. After `close()` is an IOException. In short: the answer is utterly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        FO1 = new FileWriter("ProximityPoint.txt");
        out=new PrintWriter(FO1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception 2");
    }
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for (int j=0 ;j<10;j++){
            for (int k =0; k<10 ;k++){
                /*Process is done here*/
                out.println(i+ ", " +j+ ", " +k+ ", "+ a variable);

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that I am using for writing into the file. I have omitted the actual code as I dont think it effects the writing into the file.

---

bestsss' edit here: you miss 
`out.close()` after the loop.

Comment: Oops!! Thanks a lot. It actually worked. I totally forgot to close it.
Thanks a lot!